# choose correct template specialization at run-time

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have

```
template <int i> struct a { static void f (); };
```

with specializations done at different places in the code. How can I call the correct `a<i>::f` for an `i` known only at runtime?

```
void f (int i) { a<i>::f (); } // won't compile
```

I don't want to list all possible values of `i` in a big `switch`.

Edit:

I thought of something like

```
#include <iostream>

template <int i> struct a { static void f (); };

struct regf {
  typedef void (*F)();
  enum { arrsize = 10 };
  static F v[arrsize];
  template < int i > static int apply (F f) {
    static_assert (i < arrsize, "");
    v[i] = a<i>::f;
    return 0;
  }
};
regf::F regf::v[arrsize];

template <int i> struct reg { static int dummy; };
template <int i> int reg<i>::dummy = regf::apply<i> ();

void f (int i) { return regf::v[i] (); }

#define add(i) \
  template <> struct a<i> : reg<i> { \
    static void f () { std::cout << i << "\n"; } \
  };

add(1)
add(3)
add(5)
add(7)

int main () {
  f (3);
  f (5);
}
```

but it crashes (did I miss something to force an instantiation?), and I don't like that dummy is not `static const` (and uses memory) and of course that `arrsize` is bigger than necessary.

---

Actual problem: To have a function `generate (int i)` that calls `a<i>::generate ()` to generate an instance of class `a<i>` for an `i` given only at run-time. The design (classes `a<i>`) is given, they inherit from a base class and more specializations of a could be added at any time anywhere in the code, but I don't want to force everyone to change my `generate (i)` manually as that could be forgotten easily.

Comment: Again code with an intended solution, but not the actual problem. Ask about what you want to solve. (Not what is it failing in your intended solution). Do you really need templates? Why? Specializations? Why? Do you need inheritance? Why?

Comment: I can't change the design of `struct a` (it's a simplified part of a bigger system), but I need a low-memory `f` without having to change the `switch` manually for every specialization that is added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure that this is the best solution that you can get, as there might be better designs, at any rate you can use some metaprogramming to trigger the instantiation and registry of the functions:

```
// in a single cpp file
namespace {
template <unsigned int N>
int register_a() {         // return artificially added
   register_a<N-1>();      // Initialize array from 0 to N-1
   regf::v[N] = &a<N>::f;  // and then N
   return N;
}
template <>
int register_a<0>() {
   regf::v[0] = &a<0>::f;  // recursion stop condition
   return 0;
}
const int ignored = register_a<regf::arrsize>(); // call it
}
```

That code will instantiate the functions and register pointers to the static member functions. The fake return type is required to be able to force execution of the function in an static context (by means of using that function to initialize a static value).

This is quite prone to the static initialization fiasco. While `regf::v` is ok, any code that depends on `regf::v` containing the appropriate pointers during static initialization is bound to fail. You can improve this with the usual techniques...

From the bits and pieces that you have actually posted, my guess is that you are trying to use an abstract factory with automated registration from each one of the concrete factories. There are better ways of approaching the problem, but I think that this answer solves your question (I am unsure on whether this does solve your problem).

Answer (score 4):

You have to. Templates are resolved and instantiated at compile-time. Apart from that, a `switch` needn't be inefficient. It usually compiles to a lookup table with very little overhead.

You can, however, use recursive template magic to have nested `if/else` blocks to replace the `switch` generated for you by the compiler. But a plain `switch` should be much more readable. Unless of course you have literally thousands of cases.

In either case, you need to know the set of values that `i` can have at compilation time since the compiler needs to know which templates to instantiate.

Comment: I'm specializing the class with a macro like `add (i, short-code-for-f)`. Is there a better way than updating the switch for every `add`? (as that could be forgotten and is error-prone)

Comment: @Thomas: What is the problem you actually want to solve? There are different approaches that you might be able to take depending on what you actually need. As it is, you have just posted your initial approach to a solution that fails, but without knowing the original question it is hard to answer.

Comment: In this case, the underlying problem is: choosing the right constructor for a set of classes indexed by a number. An efficient and low-memory solution would also be useful in other use cases and I can't redesign the parts that are given. But in my case, the `i`s are starting with 0 and increasing.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pick a template specialization at runtime, they're by definition chosen at compile time.

The usual ways to solve the dispatch problem you're looking at are `switch` (as you surmised) or a `vector` or `map` of `int` to function pointer.

Answer (score 1):

No, compiler needs to the instantiation of the template at *compile time*, for that it needs to know the value of `i` at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't as template instantiation is done at compile time.