# compile-time counter for template classes

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Imagine that you have a lot of classes with a lot of different template parameters. Every class has a method `static void f()`. You want to collect all these function pointers in a list L.

A run-time solution would be easy:

```
typedef void (*p)();
std::vector<p> L;
int reg (p x) { static int i = 0; L.push_back(x); return i++; } // also returns an unique id

template <typename T> struct regt { static int id; };
template <typename T> int regt<T>::id = reg (T::f);

template < typename ... T > struct class1 : regt< class1<T...> > { static void f(); };
template < typename ... T > struct class2 : regt< class2<T...> > { static void f(); };
// etc.
```

The compiler knows all `f()`s of all instantiated classes at compile-time. So, theoretically it should be possible to generate such a list (a `const std::array<p, S> L` with some `S`) as a compile-time constant list. But how? (C++0x solutions are welcome, too).

---

Why do I need this?

On an architecture with only 256 kB (for code and data), I need to generate objects for incoming ids of classes. Existing serialization frameworks or the run-time solution above are unnecessarily big. Without templates a compile-time solution would be easy, but I want to keep all the advantages templates offer.

Comment: From my understanding this is not possible, as you can't modify anything during compile-time, so you won't be able to build your list. To ease the process you can however use a "magical" base-class, that does the registration.

Comment: What would be the use-case for such a feature?

Comment: @Oli: I need to assign unique ids to all the classes (for serialization purposes) and generate instances of them when an id is given. This is on a very low-memory architecture, so I don't want to use existing serialization frameworks and the `reg`-calls of the run-time solution generate unnecessary code.

Comment: @filmor: changed the code according to your suggestion

Comment: I think I might have [answered this already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621810/choose-correct-template-specialization-at-run-time/5624015#5624015) in your other question from today, just a few minutes before you wrote this new question. Take a look at it, and if it does not fit your requirements, feel free to ask about any details.

Comment: Also note that templates will make your code section grow quite a bit. If the memory is scarce in your system (depends on what else you need to do) then reducing the code size and doing the extra bit of work manually might actually pay off.

Comment: @David: My previous question had a single class with an integer template parameter, and your solution works in that case - but here, it is first necessary to enumerate the instantiated classes somehow (which seems to be a hard, if not impossible problem)

Comment: My guess is that you cannot manually assign the ids... which is what really makes sense --as it will force consistency, automated things that depend on initialization order might endup with the same id assigned to different types in different compilations/runs of your system, which is less than optimal. You could try some fancy tricks, like defining a type list that contains all of the types that are used to instantiate the template, and then using that type list both to instantiate the templates and obtain compile time assigned ids in the shape of traits...

Comment: To be able to provide some code example, again, I would need to understand some of your requirements.... like why are the `class1` and `class2` variadic templates... or is it just pseudocode? That is, are `class1` and `class2` actual types or families of types parametrized by other types?

Comment: @David: You mean automatically instead of manually? As a *manual* assignment of the ids is easy (using your previous code), but that forces me to enumerate all template instantiations (that I want to support) manually and destroys a lot of the advantages templates could offer. The actual ids that are assigned are not important as long as they are unique during one run (after that, the data will be useless anyway).

Comment: @David: I used variadic templates only for simple demonstration of the problem. In reality, theses classes represent different behaviours that can be parametrized by different sets of parameters of fixed size.

Comment: Now, while reading my previous comment, I realize how confusing I did it... the important bit is that you probably need to have the ids generated deterministically, that is, you cannot depend on the order of execution of the different initializers. In the previous question the trivial ids would be the number with which the template was instantiated, but in this case there is no such simple number

Comment: It would be easier to discuss the details in a [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com) or similar and then write them down. For example, do you want to provide unique ids for each instantiation of the types? (i.e. one id for each combination of parameters to `class1`, or a single id for all `class1` instantiations?) Is the number of arguments to all `classN` fixed? (i.e. they are all templates with exactly 4 type arguments? or each one might have a different number of arguments?)

Comment: @David: every instantiated set of parameters for a class should have a unique id; the number of parameters for every class is fixed (and <=3 currently; no variadic templates), but it would be nice if that was not required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Manually**

The simplest thing that you can do is just roll the code manually, I don't think that there is much that can be used to your advantage from the templates, so I will use plain classes, where `A`, `B`... stand for particular instantiations of your types. That allows for compile time initialization of the types, at the cost of having to remember to update the lookup table whenever a new type is added to the system:

```
typedef void (*function_t)();
function_t func[] = {
    &A::f,
    &B::f,
    &C::f
};
```

I would recommend this, from a maintenance point of view. Automating the system will make the code much harder to understand and maintain in the future.

**Macros**

The simple most automated one, which will probably generate less code is a macro generation system is just using macros. Since this first approach will use extensive use of macros, I will generate the functions automatically, as you did in the previous question. You can remove that part of code if you have (hopefully) given up the path of full code generation through macros.

To avoid having to retype the names of the types in different contexts you can define a macro with all the data you need for any context, and then use other macros to filter what is to be used (and how) in each particular context:

```
// This is the actual list of all types, the id and the code that you were
// generating in the other question for the static function:
#define FOREACH_TYPE( macro ) \
    macro( A, 0, { std::cout << "A"; } ) \
    macro( B, 1, { std::cout << "B"; } ) \
    macro( C, 2, { std::cout << "C"; } )

// Now we use that recursive macro to:
// Create an enum and calculate the number of types used
#define ENUM_ITEM( type, id, code ) \
    e_##type,
enum AllTypes {
    FOREACH_TYPE( ENUM_ITEM )
    AllTypes_count
};
#undef ENUM_ITEM

// Now we can create an array of function pointers
typedef void (*function_t)();
function_t func[ AllTypes_count ];

// We can create all classes:
#define CREATE_TYPE( type, the_id, code ) \
struct type {\
   static const int id = the_id; \
   static void func() code\
};
FOREACH_TYPE( CREATE_TYPE )
#undef CREATE_TYPE

// And create a function that will 
#define REGISTER_TYPE( type, id, code ) \
    func[ i++ ] = &type::func;

void perform_registration() {
   int i = 0;
   FOREACH_TYPE( REGISTER_TYPE );
};
#undef REGISTER_TYPE

// And now we can test it
int main() {
   perform_registration();
   for ( int i = 0; i < AllTypes_count; ++i ) {
      func[ i ]();
   }
}
```

This is, on the other hand a maintenance nightmare, quite fragile and hard to debug. Adding new types is trivial, just add a new line to the `FOREACH_TYPE` macro and you are done... and the best of lucks once something fails...

**Templates and metaprogramming**

On the other hand, using templates you can get close but you cannot get to the single point of definition for the types. You can automate some of the operations in different ways, but at the very least you will need to define the types themselves and add them to a typelist to get the rest of the functionality.

Simplifying the definition of the actual type_list with C++0x code you can start by defining the types and then creating the `type_list`. If you want to avoid using C++0x, then take a look at the Loki library, but with C++0x a type list is simple enough:

```
template <typename ... Args> type_list {}; // generic type list
typedef type_list< A, B, C, D > types;     // our concrete list of types A, B, C and D
                                           // this is the only source of duplication:
                                           // types must be defined and added to the
                                           // type_list manually [*]
```

Now we need to use some metaprogramming to operate on the type list, we can for example count the number of elements in the list:

```
template <typename List> struct size;     // declare
template <typename T, typename ... Args>  // general case (recursion)
struct size< type_list<T,Args...> > {
   static const int value = 1 + size< type_list<Args...>::value;
};
template <>                               // stop condition for the recursion
struct size< type_list<> > {
   static const int value = 0;
};
```

Having the size of the type list is a first step in our problem, as it allows us to define an array of functions:

```
typedef void (*function_t)();                 // signature of each function pointer
struct registry {
   static const int size = ::size< types >::value;
   static const function_t table[ size ];
};
function_t registry::table[ registry::size ]; // define the array of pointers
```

Now we want to register the static functions from each particular type in that array, and for that we create an auxiliar function (encapsulated as a static function in a type to allow for partial specializations). Note that this concrete part is designed to be run during initialization: it will NOT be compile time, but the cost should be trivial (I would be more worried on the binary size with all the templates):

```
template <typename T, int N>                         // declaration
struct register_types_impl;
template <typename T, typename ... Args, int N>      // general recursion case
struct register_types_impl< type_list<T,Args...>, N> {
   static int apply() {
      registry::table[ N ] = &T::f;                  // register function pointer
      return register_types_impl< type_list<Args...>, N+1 >;
   }
};
template <int N>                                     // stop condition
struct register_types_impl< type_list<>, int N> {
   static int apply() { return N; }
};
// and a nicer interface:
int register_types() {
   register_types_impl< types, 0 >();
}
```

Now we need an id function that maps our types to the function pointer, which in our case is the position of the type in the type list

```
template <typename T, typename List, int N>      // same old, same old... declaration
struct id_impl;
template <typename T, typename U, typename ... Args, int N>
struct id_impl< T, type_list<U, Args...>, N > {  // general recursion
   static const int value = id_impl< T, type_list<Args...>, N+1 >;
};
template <typename T, typename ... Args, int N>  // stop condition 1: type found
struct id_impl< T, type_list<T, Args...>, N> {  
   static const int value = N;
};
template <typename T, int N>                     // stop condition 2: type not found
struct id_impl< T, type_list<>, N> {
   static const int value = -1;
}
// and a cleaner interface
template <typename T, typename List>
struct id {
   static const int value = id_impl<T, List, 0>::value;
};
```

Now you just need to trigger the registration at runtime, before any other code:

```
int main() {
   register_types(); // this will build the lookup table
}
```

<sup>[*]</sup> Well... sort of, you can use a macro trick to reuse the types, as the use of macros is limited, it will not be that hard to maintain/debug.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I simplified your template solution a bit: `template < typename ... T > std::array < void(*)(), sizeof...(T) > register_types () { return {{ T::f... }}; }
auto table = register_types< A, B, C, D > ();` -- The remaining (big) problem, though, is that it is hard to guess which template instantiations of all possible ones a given application will use (and of course, we don't want to generate code for all possibilities). So, it would not be wise to manually generate a list of all types that could result from template instantiations.

Comment: @Thomas: You can try to tackle it in a different way: do not provide the template definition, just the declaration. That way everything will compile and fail to link. Then in a single cpp file, include the template definitions, and use explicit instantiations. In that class you add the list of types in the `register_types`. This will require manual work, but at least the compiler (or rather the linker) will help you if you forget to instantiate a type, and while the type list is manual, it is located in a single file.

Comment: On the complexity of the solution... it is the first time I have used C++11 variadic templates, I thought on a solution using type lists as shown in Modern C++ design, and just removed a bunch of boiler plate with the variadic template. I need to get into C++11 thinking mode! (Thanks for adding the solution as a comment)

Answer (score 1):

> The compiler knows all `f()`s of all instantiated classes at compile-time.

There's your mistake.  The compiler knows nothing about template instantiations in other compilation units.  It should now be pretty obvious why the number of instantiations isn't a constant integral expression that could be used as a template argument (and what if `std::array` was specialized?  Halting Problem ahead!)

Comment: @Ben: I see, but in my case a solution is only needed for a single compilation unit.

Comment: @Thomas: You're still trying to solve the halting problem.  What if the type used for the "list" variable itself causes more templates to be used?

Comment: @Ben: You are trying to solve a problem that is more general than mine - I won't serialize the list of function pointers, so I don't need its class to possess a `f` method whose address is included in the list. I see that the problem statement in its original form was too general, but I added my use case.

Comment: @Thomas: So your case would halt, fairly quickly.  But it's still ugly, because you're still wanting the compiler to mostly compile the code, list all template instances, and then instantiate some more templates (`std::array` in your case).  C++ sidesteps the problem but not providing any way to list template instantiations during compile.  You can either introduce more stages by adding a precompilation tool that creates a list from your source code, or a postprocessing tool that creates a list from the debug database, or include code to build a list at runtime.

Comment: @Ben: You are right: This could require two stages in template instantiation. But isn't it uglier that with the run-time solution the compiler generates bloated code to dynamically insert hundreds of pointers into a vector and possibly resize it (malloc is really bad when you only have some kBs) during the process, while ideally a simple lookup-table would suffice? And the manual pre- or postprocessing is even uglier...

Comment: @Thomas: I didn't say anything about manual processing.  There are several C++ front-ends that can spit out a list of the instantiations in XML format, you can write a script that reads that xml and spits out C++ code for an initialized array.

Comment: @Ben: I'm using g++ 4.6 (with c++0x features), and no such extension seems to exist. Do you know if it is supported (and if yes, are there any examples to parse it)?

Comment: @Thomas: g++ isn't the only C++ analyzer in town.  I know that doxygen has one, and generates xml from the parse tree, I'm not sure how it reports specializations and instantiations of a template, however.