# Multiple-instance per-type counter

Tags: c++, templates

Sounds like an easy one but I can't figure a suitable solution to this: For register allocator I need a counter that starts counting from 0 and increments on each allocation step.

Ok, lets make this a general problem (not specific to register allocation): I need a class that can have multiple instances (that's important!) and that has a templated member function that returns an integer which's value is counting up on each call. The interface should look like:

```
class Counter
{
public:
  template<class T>
  int plus1() {
    // ?
  }
private:
  // what member ?
};
```

When one uses the counter it should function like this:

```
int main() {
  Counter a,b;

  assert( a.plus1<int>() == 0);    
  assert( a.plus1<int>() == 1);    

  assert( b.plus1<float>() == 0);  
  assert( b.plus1<float>() == 1);  

  assert( a.plus1<float>() == 0);  
}
```

Obviously when relaxing the "multiple instances" requirement this can be implemented with a `static int` local variable . However I need multiple instances, and I think this makes the whole thing tricky.

*** SOLUTION/EDIT ***

I think @log0 gave the right solution. Here for completeness the full working C++11 code (at least it seems to work):

```
class Counter
{
public:
  template<class T>
  int plus1() {
    return counters[ std::type_index( typeid(T) ) ]++;
  }
private:
  std::map<std::type_index, int> counters;
};
```

Comment: is RTTI available? (evilish dynamic_cast idea in the back of my head)

Comment: @Najzero It would be better if doesn't use RTTI. Is it possible without it?

Comment: @chris How would a static function solve the issue of a multiple-instance counter?

Comment: @Frank , well without it you are pretty much down to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623910/compile-time-counter-for-template-classes (see Davids answer)

Comment: @Frank, I misunderstood your question, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use type_index (c++11)

```
class Counter
{
public:
  template<class T>
  int plus1() {
    return map_[std::type_index(typeid(T))]++;
  }
private:
  std::map<std::type_index, int> map_;
};
```

`typeid` is deduced at compile time if not called on reference to polymorphic object.

Comment: Not sure: `std::type_info` does not implement `operator<` which is needed for `std::map`

Comment: @Frank Yes I corrected my answer.`type_index` is the appropriate key type.

Comment: @log0 Can you please provide the full working code? I can't see the object dependence here.

Comment: Fantastic! That's a great application of the new C++11 features!

Comment: And it doesn't use RTTI does it?

Comment: @log0 Thanks! Now I got it:) I shared the map between objects for one type and this shares the map between types for one object:) +1

Comment: @Frank If you directly give a type and not an expression. RTTI are not used: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
class Counter
{
    public:
        template<class T>
        int plus1()
        {
            static std::map<Counter*, int> s_counters;
            return s_counters[this]++;
        }
};
```

It's type and object dependent. Not very elegant...

Comment: It can certainly do it. But you will understand that I give the right answer to @log0 because it is more elegant (as you say). +1 anyway